# Build failing when running an Android app with Bazel

Tags: android, macos, build, android-emulator, bazel

I am trying to follow a tutorial to build an Android app using Bazel as given here:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/android-app.html. The app is being built successfully with the command:

```
bazel build //src/main:app
```

However, when I try to run the app using the command `bazel mobile-install //src/main:app`  the build is failing with the following error:

INFO: Analyzed target //src/main:app (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/kanzashaikh/examples/android/tutorial/src/main/BUILD:1:15: Installing //src/main:app failed: (Exit 1): incremental_install failed: error executing command bazel-out/darwin-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/incremental_install --output_marker bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/src/main/app_files/full_deploy_marker --dexmanifest ... (remaining 11 argument(s) skipped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_kanzashaikh/df06cea5303c222cca918b7a24c9d8ca/execroot/**main**/bazel-out/darwin-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/incremental_install.runfiles/bazel_tools/tools/android/incremental_install.py", line 25, in 
from concurrent import futures
ImportError: No module named concurrent
Target //src/main:app failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.311s, Critical Path: 0.19s
INFO: 3 processes: 3 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bazel is using python2 (the `py2` from `darwin-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6` from the file paths), but `from concurrent import futures` in incremental_install.py doesn't work in python2.

If you don't have python3 installed, try installing it and seeing if that fixes the problem.

If you do have python3 installed, then check your bazel version, older versions of bazel might be defaulting to python2.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! So I did check my python and bazel version and both are updated. Python version is 3.9.5 and bazel version is 4.1.0. However, the problem persists. Do I specifically need to tell bazel to use python 3 somehow? or should it detect it on its own? If I need to tell it specifically, can you please tell me how can it be done?

Comment: I would like to add that when I run my python3 shell in the terminal and run the command 'from concurrent import futures', it gives me no errors at all. So, I'm assuming that bazel is somehow using python2 or it's referencing some other concurrent file but I also looked up any files named concurrent in my system but there were none.